# How adding check-box on listview when activating multiple item selected listener?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I want to check a check box when I select (activate) item on list view and I want non selected item has a uncheck-box, and to finish, I doesn"t want to display check box when no one item is selected, like this (left when non display the check box, and right when selected one or many items, I use multiple slected item listener on list view) :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1pGazzf7cP4dHNxMVN2bVdzNFE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You should add an imageview (look like a checkbox) in each item of listview
Then you create one variable type boolean like **noItemSelected** (default: true, when you select any item then you set it to false)
And in your array data you add **isItemSelected** for display item checked or uncheck
I think it will solve your problem